# Skip the zero values present and change the format of dates in some particular columns in .csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a table where there are four columns consisting of dates in simple numbers (without any separator). There are some rows in 4th column having 0 instead of date, which I want to skip(not drop) and change the format of other dates to DD/MM/YYYY

| Date1. | date2 | date3 | date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200122 | 20201012 | 20210424 | 20180710 |
| 20190315 | 20210120 | 20180710 | 0 |
| 20220514 | 20200122 | 20200122 | 0 |
| 20180317 | 20200122 | 20201003 | 20200122 |
| 20201003 | 20200122 | 20200122 | 20171203 |
| 20171203 | 20200122 | 20200122 | 0 |
| 20210423 | 20200122 | 20200122 | 20190315 |

The output should be:

| Date1. | date2 | date3 | date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/01/2020 | 12/10/2020 | 24/04/2021 | 10/07/2018 |
| 15/03/2019 | 12/10/2021 | 10/07/2018 | 0 |
| 14/05/2022 | 12/10/2020 | 22/01/2020 | 0 |
| 17/03/2018 | 12/10/2020 | 03/10/2020 | 22/01/2020 |
| 03/10/2020 | 12/10/2020 | 22/01/2020 | 03/12/2017 |
| 03/12/2017 | 12/10/2020 | 22/01/2020 | 0 |
| 23/04/2021 | 12/10/2020 | 22/01/2020 | 15/03/2019 |

Logic: The dates in the first table should change to a format of DD/MM/YYYY and for the 4th column it should ignore the 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `date4` column to datetime by `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` which treats mismatched time as NaT then convert it to string with `.dt.strftime` and at last fill the NaT with original mismatched time.

```py
df['date4'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date4'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
               .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
               .fillna(df['date4'])) # or fillna(0)
```

```
print(df)

     Date1.     date2     date3       date4
0  20200122  20201012  20210424  10/07/2018
1  20190315  20210120  20180710           0
2  20220514  20200122  20200122           0
3  20180317  20200122  20201003  22/01/2020
4  20201003  20200122  20200122  03/12/2017
5  20171203  20200122  20200122           0
6  20210423  20200122  20200122  15/03/2019
```